# Sending FormData using AJAX to nodejs + express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

Here is my frontend JS. As a side note, FormData.append()  does not work, so I have to set its properties explicitly. `@data` is an object with input name: value properties.

```
function http(data) {
 
   const httpData = new FormData();
    for (let prop in data) {
        httpData[prop] = data[prop];
    }
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            const status = this.status;
            const data = this.responseText;

        }
    };
    xhttp.open('POST', '/api/login');
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send(httpData);
}
```

And on the server side

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
 }));
```

express ready to parse form data, and in the `/routes/api.js` (I am using express router)

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

I got `req.body` as an `{}`

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems.

1. `append()` **does** work. It just doesn't store the data in a way that shows up with `console.log`. Assigning arbitrary properties **doesn't** work.
2. You need to send the **correct** `Content-Type` header. This is `multipart/form-data` with a **mandatory** `boundary` parameter that you have no way of knowing. **Don't try to set the `Content-Type` header manually**. `XMLHttpRequest` will generate it automatically from the FormData object.
3. You need a body parser for Express that supports `multipart/form-data`. The built-in one does not. The [documentation for it on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) suggests 4 alternatives.